# Roots of BesselJ

Tags: equation-solving

`BesselJ[0,x]` is a smooth quasiperiodic function.
NSolve is able to find all roots in the given range `0<x<50`:

```
erg = NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 0 < x < 50}, x, Reals]
Show[{Plot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 50}] , Graphics[Point[{x, 0} /. erg]]}]
```

[image]

But if I increase the range  `0<x<100` NSolve misses many of the expected 32 roots.

```
erg = NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 0 < x < 100}, x, Reals]
Show[{Plot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 100}] ,Graphics[Point[{x, 0} /. erg]]}]
```

[image]

Any idea why NSolve fails? Is there some kind of  *critical argumentsize x* in the definition of `BesselJ[0,x]`? Thanks!

Comment: FYI it doesn't fail on mathematica 11.3 macOS

Comment: @ chris:Thanks. My version 11.0.1.0 (Windows 64) only detects 18 (of the expected 31?) roots in `NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 0 < x < 100 }, x, Reals]`

Comment: It fails on Version 11.3, Windows 64, only 18 roots.

Comment: Version 8.0 on Windows 32 has no problem to find all 32 roots.

Comment: Linux Version does not fail, even for 200 where it finds 63 roots ($Version 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

Increasing the `WorkingPrecision` improves the performance of `NSolve`

```
Manipulate[
 erg = NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 0 < x < 100}, x, Reals,
   WorkingPrecision -> wp];
 Show[{
   Plot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 100}],
   Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{x, 0} /. erg]}]}],
 {{wp, Automatic, "WorkingPrecision"},
  {Automatic, Range[20, 30, 2]} // Flatten,
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'm still wondering that such a smooth function needs such an amount of WorkingPrecision to calculate the roots...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this would qualify  as a  workaround for what you want to do but this works.

```
tt = Table[BesselJZero[0, i] // N, {i, 25}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
rr=FindRoot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, # - 1, # + 1}] & /@ tt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[Plot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 100}], 
 Graphics[ Point /@ ({x, 0} /. rr)]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to argue that this is a bug.

The roots are roughly located and polished with `FindRoot` at a `WorkingPrecision` of `10` plus the `WorkingPrecision` of `NSolve`.  In this case that is ten more than machine precision, or `MachinePrecision + 10`, which is about `26.95` digits.
We can see that all 32 roots are found.

```
fn = BesselJ[0, #] &;  (* for convenience *)

rts0 = Trace[
      NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 0 < x < 100}, x, Reals],
      HoldPattern[f : FindRoot[_, {v_, _}, ___]] :> (v /. f),
      TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // ReleaseHold // Sort;

Plot[fn[x], {x, 0, 100},
 PlotLabel -> Row[{Length@rts, "roots"}, " "],
 Epilog -> {Red, Point@Thread[{rts0, 0}]}]
```

[image]

`NSolve` then set the roots to the arbitrary-precision equivalent of the working precision, which in this case is `$MachinePrecision` and deletes the value of `x` for which `fn[x]` is nonzero:

```
rts = SetPrecision[rts0, $MachinePrecision];

ListPlot[
 fn[rts] /. r_ /; r == 0 :> 0 // RealExponent,
 GridLines -> {Flatten@Position[fn[rts], r_ /; r != 0], None},
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Indices of final roots, rejected with nonzero residual"
 ]
```

[image]

```
Trace[
  NSolve[{BesselJ[0, x], 0 < x < 100}, x, Reals],
  HoldPattern[Select[_, Function[_Equal]]],
  TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The real problem is that at an arbitrary-precision of `$MachinePrecision` there is no number near each discarded root that can make the Bessel function evaluate to an arbitrary-precision zero.  (It's the nature of a finite machine that not every real number can be represented.)  Usually what happens at the closest arbitrary-precision number to a root is that the round-off error bound calculated by the arbitrary-precision code is greater than the computed value of `fn[x]` at a zero `x`, and an arbitrary-precision zero is returned.  I suspect the assumption was that this always happens, but apparently it does not.

Comment: Thank you for  your detailed explanation, which shows the imprecision of numerics. I'm still wondering how to check additionaly numerical calculations...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You're welcome.  I don't know your last comment is supposed to be a question for me or not.  I can add that `BesselJ[]` seems to exhibit interesting precision-loss issues as the working precision changes.  It suggests to me that it switches algorithms depending on the argument and precision.  Nothing very dramatic.  I don't understand it at all and could not figure out how to incorporate into my answer.  It may have nothing to do with the problem at hand, or it possibly might explain why `NSolve` fails here.